# InputFormatter should allow negative and decimal numbers

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, inputformatter

I want to allow users to just adding numbers like
123456.78912445,
-12345.7777777899,
1234567,
-12345678.
There is no number limit.
How can i write Regrex pattern for this textformfield.
Same Question [inputFormatter should allow just decimal numbers and negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64117471/inputformatter-should-allow-just-decimal-numbers-and-negative-numbers)

```
TextFormField(inputFormatters:[FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp())])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `^\-*\d+(?:.\d+)?$`

And example: https://regex101.com/r/yQDyoM/1